# Crucible Comment Box Annoying

Tags: atlassian-crucible

When I read, particularly when reading code, I like to highlight the line that I'm reading, or the line where the code block started for a visual reference on where I'm at. The problem in Crucible is, when I try to highlight a line (by habbit) it triggers the line comment box to automatically open up. Is there any way to turn this off, or change the trigger to something like "cntrl+click" opens the comment box?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't invested the time into doing it, but you should consider writing a greasmonkey script that would capture your click events and only perform the action if control is held down.

If you're not familiar with greasmonkey, see the wiki here: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page